# Get-Process Couldn't Connect to remote machine

Tags: powershell

I was recently attempting to setup a script using powershell so that I could monitor a critical process on a remote computer.

```
Get-Process -ComputerName myremotepc myprocess
```

This was giving me the following error.

```
Get-Process : Couldn't connect to remote machine.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Process -ComputerName myremotepc myprocess
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Process],     InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :     System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
```

After checking to see that the correct services were enabled. I still can not connect.

Answer (score 1):

Do note it states explicitly that `PSRemoting` does not need to be enabled.  The difference was likely your elevated prompt or a firewall exception.

```
PS C:\> Get-Help Get-Process -Parameter 'ComputerName'

-ComputerName <String[]>
    Specifies the computers for which this cmdlet gets active processes. The default is the local computer.

    Type the NetBIOS name, an IP address, or a fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of one or more computers. To specify the local computer, type the computer name, a dot (.), or localhost.

    This parameter does not rely on Windows PowerShell remoting. You can use the ComputerName parameter of this cmdlet even if your computer is not configured to run remote commands.

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value                None
    Accept pipeline input?       True (ByPropertyName)
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

Comment: I can confirm that PS Remoting is not required. I work in an environment where PS Remoting is not enabled and I routinely use Get-Process.

Comment: I'm running this from a script. I just tested another computer that did not have remoting turn on and it failed. I could be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To get this working I had to start the `Remote Registry` service on the remote computer as per this answer:

https://serverfault.com/a/717837/240263

Answer (score -2):

I came across the following link.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/projectserver/en-US/f58c4ca9-0708-401a-8d66-86195006174d/simple-remote-command-getprocess-how-to-get-the-two-machines-talking-to-each-other?forum=winserverpowershell

On that page one user suggested that enable remoting be turned on in powershell for the pc you want to connect to.

```
# Enable Remoting
Enable-PSRemoting
```

After running this in powershell in an elevated prompt I can query the remote pc.

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
811      38        27696      28568   233              3196 explorer
```